# deny unknown-clients dhcpd.conf

Tags: dhcp-server

I'm having troubles figuring out how to set up my dhcpd.conf.  I am rather new to this.
I want to allow booting and only allow the clients listed below to get their fixed address.
I do not know how to properly place items in this file.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?
Here is my file, with obvious ip addresses covered up:

```
allow booting;
option domain-name "my domain";
option domain-name-servers ip1, ip2;
subnet ip.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
    option routers ip.1;
    pool {
            range ip.10 ip.14;
            allow members of "clients";
            deny unkown-clients;
    }
}
class "clients" {
    host client1 {
            option host-name "client1.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.10;

    }
    host client2 {
            option host-name "client2.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.11;
    }
    host client3 {
            option host-name "client3.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.12;
    }
    host client4 {
            option host-name "client4.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.13;
    }
    host client5 {
            option host-name "client5.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.14;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `match` statement in your `class`, so it is not actually used. You also seem to misunderstand what classes are for: this is definitely not a situation that needs a `class` (or a `pool`).

The following will do:

```
allow booting;
option domain-name "my domain";
option domain-name-servers ip1, ip2;
subnet ip.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
    option routers ip.1;
    deny unknown-clients;
    host client1 {
            option host-name "client1.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.10;

    }
    host client2 {
            option host-name "client2.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.11;
    }
    host client3 {
            option host-name "client3.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.12;
    }
    host client4 {
            option host-name "client4.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.13;
    }
    host client5 {
            option host-name "client5.nlothame.nbr.cs.uiowa.edu";
            fixed-address ip.14;
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a small mistake. It's deny unknown-clients; instead of deny unkown-clients;

I can't edit since it's less than 6 char... Same for OP

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a more simplified version.
Under your subnet declaration you have to add

```
deny unknown-clients;
```

Be ready for calls from unknown or accounted for users/devices and also if this is critical infrastructure and things like KVMs and switches, routers are getting an address that you find their IP and MAC and add an appropriate host declaration.

The agreed on answer has a minor typo that threw me for a loop make sure "unknown-clients" is spelled correctly or your DHCP server will fail to restart.

Comment: This tells much about testing your configuration before restarting services. At the very least linting it to ensure it has no syntax mistakes. Many servers allow for that. dhcpd, sshd, nginx, php… bind have its own toolset for extensive testing of all parts of the config.